# VBA Excel sort range by specific column

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a table that can contain any number of rows:

[image]

As I said it can contain 1 or ∞ rows.

I want to sort range `A3:D∞` by the Date cell that is in column B.
How can I do it?

The problem is that I don't know how to select from `A3` to the last row.

I think that looping to the last row is not a correct method.

I have got this so far it sorts looks like correct, but the range is hard-coded.
  How do I get rid of the hard-coding of the range?

```
Range("A3:D8").Sort key1:=Range("B3:B8"), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A3:D" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("B3:B" & lastrow), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Just a note: this doesn't work too well with datetimes data type, which are sorted as strings. Its safer to convert the fields to long and then sort.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer explained why the OP's code didn't work and then explains why this code given does work.

Comment: It is enough to specify any one cell in the column used for sorting and removes the need for dynamic tracking of number of rows for the `key1` parameter. `Range("A3:D" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("B4"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo` works here too

Answer (score 16):

Or this:

```
Range("A2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).Sort Key1:=[b3], _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: I like this answer since it does not involve an additional variable

Comment: @sonyisda1 that's a bad reason, you could just replace the variable with the formula. But it is more clear what happens with the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort any range in a very dynamic way by using the `SortRange` and `GetCurrentRegionStartingGivenCell` function in Xatocode as follows:

```
' First you may define a worksheet level named range in cell "A2" and name it as rngData
Sub SortExample()

    Dim rngData         As Range ' Range to sort

    Set rngData = GetCurrentRegionStartingGivenCell(shtData.Range("rngData"))  
    Call SortRange(rngData, True, 2, xlAscending, 3, xlDescending)

End Sub
```

You can read the complete article [here](https://xatocode.com/article/1003/excel-vba-easiest-way-to-sort-range-by-specific-column)

Answer (score -2):

If the starting cell of the range and of the key is static, the solution can be very simple:

```
Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Sort key1:=Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)