# Sort range of cells in single column using excel vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to sort a range of cells using Excel VBA macro

I have searched many websites but everywhere the examples show how to sort multiple columns with a single key

e.g. this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451458/vba-excel-sort-range)

[Example Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk5NT.png)

In example above I want to sort cells A2 to A8, that's it.
For this my code is

```
Range("A2:A8").Sort
```

But it is giving Runtime error 1004

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
sub test()
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A8").sort key1:=Range("A2:A8"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End sub
```

Comment: `Range("A2:A8").Sort key1 := Range("A2")` is enough. There seems to be an inconsistency in the documentation. All parameters in the `Sort` method are listed as being optional, which suggests that if you pass no parameters it defaults to what you get when you select a range and hit the sort button -- but it throws an error when you try to invoke it without any of the "optional" parameters.

Comment: Thanks Mick17 and @John Coleman. Finally done. Really, small mistake in documentation took hours of me.