# select cell in random location and delete vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have only started coding a few months ago. I am trying to arrange random numbers in a column in descending order. In the route I've chosen to go, I'm trying to find a simple code to select a cell with a specific value (the minimum number in the column), regardless of it's location in column.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: look into the SMALL function.

Comment: `I am trying to arrange random numbers in a column in descending order` Look into `.Sort`. To find the smallest number in a range, and delete it use `.Find`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @SamanthaTonog If my answer works as you asked please accept it by hitting the button below the up/down vote! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Sort` function to sort your column by ascending or descending order.

Here is a code to order `Column A` as an example:

```
Sub OrderColumnDescending()
    Dim lastrow As Long

    'If you change the column change the 1 with the number
    'of your column to order
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("A1:A" & lastrow), _
        order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

---

Since you said you're new to VBA, here are some explanations about the code.

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

This line get the last used row in the Column number 1, I put the value in the `lastrow` variable so I can use it later. It's better than fixed values and more readable than writting the whole thing everytime.

```
Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("A1:A" & lastrow), _
        order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
```

I create a Range object containing cells from A1 to A**X** where **X** is the last row used in column A that we calculated earlier. From this Range I call its `Sort` method and give its `Key1`, `Order1` and `Header` parameters.

Here are useful links about the `Range.Sort` method.

[MSDN - Range.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel)

[Stack Overflow - VBA Excel sort range by specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451458/vba-excel-sort-range-by-specific-column)