# Sort Table excluding first row

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I want to sort a table that already has headers with vba but it needs to exclude the first row as this has formula in it that is needed.

Is there a way to do this?
[image: Sort Table]

Comment: Simply delete the first line underneath the header. Then sort by the relevant column(s)

Comment: Please add the code you're using and we can help adjust it for you so it starts from the second row.

Comment: Yes; use the `Range.Sort` method. See the First Answer by Dmitry Pavliv to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451458/vba-excel-sort-range-by-specific-column)

Comment: @GMalc Ah ok, i will have a look at it, thanks. For the moment, i found that if i hide the row, it excludes it from the sort